# how to remove an element using class

Tags: javascript, object, getelementsbyclassname

I want to remove all elements when clicking a button that have the same class "box". I have looked up several examples where people do this, but I'm still having trouble figuring out how to do it for my code.

I have this function which adds a box to the DOM when a button is clicked.

```
 function addBox(newbox) {                                   
   var scene = document.getElementById("scene"); //where all new divs will go        
   var div = document.createElement("div");                   
   div.className += " " + "box";            // assigns the class "box" to all divs
   div.innerHTML += newbox.name; 
   div.style.backgroundColor = newbox.color;                            
   scene.appendChild(div);                                    
  }
```

This is the function I'm working on to try to clear all of the new divs when a different button is clicked.

```
  function clear() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  for ( k = elems.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
   parentElement.removeChild(elems[k]);
  }
  }
```

The warning that I'm getting in the console is "parentElement is not defined". I have been trying to figure out how to define the parent element but I'm having trouble. any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: parentElement **hasn't been defined** by you.  if you put `var parentElement = elems[k].parentNode;` in your for loop above the `removeChild` line, it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab the parent from the element's [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode) property:

```
function clear() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
    for (var k = elems.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        var parent = elems[k].parentNode;
        parent.removeChild(elems[k]);
    }
}
```